# What is the best way to versoining in install/ upgrade scripts?

Tags: magento-1.7, versioning, sql-scripts

Sometimes, I use any of the following mentioned names to name the install/upgrade scripts in custom modules:

```
install-0.1.0.0.php
upgrade-0.1.0.0-0.1.1.0.php
upgrade-0.1.1.0-0.1.2.0.php

----------------------------

install-0.1.0.php
upgrade-0.1.0.0-0.1.1.php
upgrade-0.1.1-0.1.2.php
```

Is there a standard way to follow for this naming conventions for install/upgrade scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning follows some conventions/standards, here is the code snippet from Mage.php to give an idea how module versions can be decided. This is for Magento version 1.7.0.2

array(
        'major'     => '1',
        'minor'     => '7',
        'revision'  => '0',
        'patch'     => '2',
        'stability' => '',
        'number'    => '',
    );

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there's no standard way and you can name your scripts and versions as you need( it uses php `version_compare` anyway).